# Is it possible to use custom data models with Google Natural Language API?

Tags: google-cloud-nl

I've been doing some research about pricing and functionality of some NLP services.

I recently came across with Google's, however, I've been unable to find any information on their docs about using a custom data model, as we need to identify some very specific tags on the content we parse on a project.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: It appears the answer is "not yet" - Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094100/provide-custom-entities-to-google-nlp-engine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Train or Custom Word Entity Types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496045/train-or-custom-word-entity-types)

Answer (score 0):

Google NLP API currently does not provide functionality  for adding custom entities.